# Function return type based on conditional parameter's value

Tags: typescript

I have a function, which accepts 2 parameters, that returns either a string|undefined, or a Buffer|undefined, depending on the value of the 2nd parameter.

```
const readAsync = (path:string, returnAs?:"utf8"|"buffer") => {
     const data = await FileSystem.readAsBuffer(path);
     if (!data) return undefined; //Returns undefined
     if (returnAs === "buffer") return data; //Returns buffer
     return Buffer.from(data).toString(); //Returns a string
}
```

If the 2nd parameter is not specified or is "utf8", the result should be Promise<string|undefined>, but if the parameter is "buffer", then return type should be Promise<Buffer|undefined>.

However, the return type that I get is Promise<string|Buffer|undefined>, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case for using a [function overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```ts
async function readAsync (path: string, returnAs?: 'utf8'): Promise<string | undefined>;
async function readAsync (path: string, returnAs: 'buffer'): Promise<Buffer | undefined>;
async function readAsync (path: string, returnAs?: 'utf8' | 'buffer') {
  // implementation of function
}

const result1 = readAsync('path'); // Promise<string | undefined>
const result2 = readAsync('path', 'utf8'); // Promise<string | undefined>
const result3 = readAsync('path', 'buffer'); // Promise<Buffer | undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible through generics, but even if it is, I think it would be ugly. I would solve the problem this way if possible:

```
const readToBufferAsync(path: string): Promise<Buffer> => {
    const data = await FileSystem.readAsBuffer(path);
    if (!data) { return undefined; }
}

const readToStringAsync(path: string): Promise<string> {
    const buffer = await readToBufferAsync(path);
    return Buffer.from(data).toString();
}
```

You generally want to avoid [stringly typed](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) solutions like passing in options or flags to a function as strings.